# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOneBy' of undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, repository-pattern

[image]I'm new to Nestjs, and while working with it using these versions of typeOrm "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1", "typeorm": "^0.3.11", I'm getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOneBy' of undefined" that I really don't understand why.  so I read that findOne is deprecated and I can use findByOne instead. but every time I try to test using postman. I get this error. attached is the error in the terminal below. any help at all on how to resolve this will be much appreciated i

I have tried changing the version of typeorm to a lower one version "^0.2.32", which fixed the error but it introduced another error at the point of running it. but i will like to work with the updated version i have searched online to see if i can find any help at all, but none that is related to my issue.

here is my code. also, I noticed that the EntityRepository is struck out as it's deprecated.

tasks.repository

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Task } from './task.entity';

@Injectable()
@EntityRepository(Task)
export class TasksRepository extends Repository<Task> {}

tasks.controller.ts

import {
Body,
Controller,
Get,
Param,
Post,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateTaskDto } from './dto/create-task.dto';
import { Task } from './task.entity';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';

@Controller('tasks')
export class TasksController {
constructor(private tasksService: TasksService) {}

@Get('/:id')
getTaskById(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<Task> {
return this.tasksService.getTaskById(id);
```

}

```
@Post()
createTask(@Body() createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<Task> 
{
 return this.tasksService.createTask(createTaskDto);
}
```

}

tasks.service

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksRepository } from './task.repository';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Task } from './task.entity';
import { TaskStatus } from './task-status.enum';
import { CreateTaskDto } from './dto/create-task.dto';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
constructor(
@InjectRepository(TasksRepository)
private taskRepository: TasksRepository,
) {}


async getTaskById(id: string): Promise<Task> {
const found = await this.taskRepository.findOneBy({ id: id });
if (!found) {
  throw new NotFoundException(`Task with ID "${id}" not 
found`);
  }

return found;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code, so we can understand the context

Comment: Hello @kusiaga, I've posted my code.

Comment: Why are you making a custom `TaskRepository`, why is it marked as `@Injectable()`, and do you have `TypeormModule.forFeature([Task])` in the `TasksModule`'s `imports`

Comment: The custom TaskRepository was what I got from the research I did apparently it doesn't work. Yes, I have this TypeormModule.forFeature([Task]) in the TasksModule's imports.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, in your repository, you are missing entity manager and you need to provide one calling the `super()` inside custom repository constructor.

There are several ways how you can approach, and those can be found in typeorm docs and nestjs docs:

1. https://typeorm.io/custom-repository
2. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern and https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern
3. sticking with custom repositories, and that can be searched and found on internet

I am just finishing with the migration from typeorm `0.2.45` to `0.3.11` and to `@nestjs/typeorm` `9.0.1`.

Our code base consists of 70+ custom repositories, which are used on many places: services, tests, seeds, fixes (something like custom migrations)...
For that reason, for now we stick to the custom class repositories (as before), although I am not sure if that is way to go. At least app seems to work, tests are passing. But maybe we will update things in iterations, once we have more feedback in community - which are preferred ways and which are not (and why).

**App.module.ts**

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (appConfig: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        ...config.database,
        entities: [`${__dirname}/modules/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}`],
      }),
      dataSourceFactory: async (dataSourceOptions) => {
        const dataSource = await new DataSource(dataSourceOptions).initialize();
        return dataSource;
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
```

**repository.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  constructor(private readonly emanager: EntityManager) {
    super(User, emanager);
  }
  // down we have custom logic-methods...
```

**user.service.ts**

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly dataSource: DataSource,
    private readonly userRepo: UserRepository,
```

**user.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
    ...
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService, UserRepository],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

For the end, very important, transactions pseudocode inside `user.service.ts`:

```
await this.dataSource.transaction(async (tManager) => {
   const userRepo = new UserRepository(tManager);
   ...
```

I shared this mainly to get (bad or good) feedback from community.

Answer (score 0):

You can also update your config file to include the following (if it, like mine, only cited the .ts extension)

> entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],